# After enabling Wayland on Ubuntu 21.10 Nvidia stopped working

Tags: nvidia

I've PC with Ubuntu 21.10.

**On X11**

When running desktop using X11 my Nvidia drivers works fine, game performance is good.

[image: Nvidia X Server settings on X11]

**On Wayland**

When I'm running desktop using Wayland, desktop itself runs very good, however I cannot setup native resolution in Steam games (3440 x 1440) and performance is very poor.

Additionally, I cannot see Nvidia X Server settings (empty window).

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings on Wayland]

On both Wayland and X11 drivers seems to works fine:

[image: Nvidia drivers]

**Question**
Maybe somehow on Wayland Nouveau drivers are used? How can I check it further?

Comment: We are looking at a screenshot of your desktop environment, so it's clear that your drivers are working, at least in some capacity.  You should edit your question with more details and context. What exactly isn't working?  What exact steps did you take that caused the problem and have you tried to revert those changes?  Does reverting those changes solve the issue?

Comment: Nvidia with Wayland is still very much experimental.

Comment: Yes... Nvidia and Wayland don't really work together yet. Best to switch back to xorg/X11.

Comment: I've edited it as requested hopefully now it is more clear.

Comment: Wayland is supposed to work with Nvidia in Ubuntu 21.10.  I've tried answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369250/how-do-i-enable-wayland-on-ubuntu-21-10-nvidia) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334825/what-are-the-steps-to-run-wayland-on-21-04-with-optimus-nvidia/1334826#1334826). I haven't had success, but may be they will work for your situation?

Comment: @PJSingh: I've checked mentioned by you questions and those actually led to current situation. What is even more interesting is that recently I was using Debian 11, and there Wayland and Nvidia works out of the box.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 Beta and Nvidia 510 driver. I had the same problem. Wayland does not work but Xorg does.